Ground pigtail to metal box
I am installing a leviton Decora no neutral smart switch. The switch has a ground coming off of it, and instructions say it must be grounded. The box is metal and has black wire and white wire heading to a light overhead.
As far as I can tell, the box is grounded. When I touch multimeter probe to either wire and the box, I get a reading around 120. Does this mean that I can safely add a pigtail to the back of the box? Or is there anything else to consider?


One wire(the switched hot) should only show 120v when the switch is on.  120v is usually good for a ground test.  If no ground wire on the box, good chance you have conduit or metal covered cables.  White can only be used as neutral in conduit.

Can you post photos of the inside of the box please?

@crip659 Yeah, that makes sense. I had tested originally with the wires still attached to the switch. Tested again without and indeed, only the black/white wire shows 120v.

@ThreePhaseEel posting a photo of the box in the original

You appear to have a switch loop. This should be wired with a non-smart switch as follows:

White marked with black tape or other marking = always hot ("line")
Black = switched hot ("load")
Box = ground

Turn off the breaker. Carefully separate the black and white wires so they are not touching each other and not touching the box. Turn on the breaker. You should get 120V between always hot and the box and 0V between switched hot and the box. That should let you determine for sure which wire is line and which is load, which you need to know for switch installation. It will also confirm that the box is grounded.
Assuming the box is grounded and you have identified line and load, you are ready to install. But there are some complications due to the switch loop with a smart switch:

The instructions actually recommend against using a metal box. I prefer metal boxes and you really don't have much choice in the matter. The reason is almost certainly not ground, as the metal box does that quite well. The problem is that metal can block RF transmissions and this switch needs to communicate with other switches and things.
While most ordinary switches, and some smart switches (generally the ones that require neutral) can ground through the metal yoke to a metal box, this one most likely uses ground to actually conduct electricity under normal use! You can only do that under certain constraints - in particular, very low power. I am pretty sure that is why this smart switch needs a separate WiFi device (MLWSB Wi-Fi Bridge) for internet connection - the permitted power via ground is enough for communication between Leviton devices but not for WiFi.
While in theory the ground wire can be connected with a screw directly to the metal box, I think you would probably be better off installing a ground screw with a wire attached, such as this Ideal from Amazon:


and wire nut it to the switch green wire.

This seems to be correct for my set up. And yeah, I know about the RF issue, we'll see how it works out, this will be the only way to add another switch to the light without spending too much money on a small convenience.
Also, confirmed that white/black wire reads 120v when touching the box, and doesn't read anything when just the black wire is tested. So, does that typically mean that it is for sure grounded? Or are there any situations you are aware of where you may still be ungrounded?

That means it is either "properly grounded" or "royally messed up." Reasonable to go with "properly grounded". In particular since the common messed up situation is to connect to neutral but appear to be grounded, and that simply isn't going to happen with a switch loop like this because there is no neutral in the box.

@larochey the box is indeed grounded to at least some degree, and likely properly grounded given that that looks like thermoplastic insulation on the conductors in the armored cable

@ThreePhaseEel Agreed. Thank you! As long as I have you here, what does it mean when I test an outlet with my multimeter, and i get a 120 reading from the hot, and 0 from the neutral when testing for ground. but after i install the outlet, i get a 120 reading from the hot but 0 from the neutral when testing the outlet it self? To my understanding, that means it is not grounded properly, right?. at the same time, my klein outlet tester says it's correct wiring, doesn't come up as open ground.

@larochey I'm not sure what you are saying there. What should happen with a metal box that self-grounds the receptacle via the yoke is that: Receptacle wired to hot/neutral but not stuffed in the box: hot/neutral 120, hot/ground open, neutral/ground open; installed: hot/neutral 120, hot/ground 120, neutral/ground 0 (continuity).

@larochey -- 120 and 0 relative to what?

Understood, I'm not great at articulating everything. With outlet wired and stuffed in the box, hot/ground is 120 neutral/ground is 0. I had thought both should read 120. But, it sounds like that's not the case

@larochey -- if you are reading something other than about 0v from neutral to ground, it means you have a broken neutral somewhere (and stuff wouldn't be working as a result), as neutral is bonded to ground at the main panel
